# How to use Liquibase to update database in embedded Glassfish instance

Tags: maven, glassfish, liquibase, glassfish-embedded, maven-glassfish-plugin

I'm in the process of converting our db management to Liquibase. This is running along nicely.

As a subsequent step I want to assure that all future modifications gets tested before deploy to common environments, continuous integration style. I try to do this using the following setup:

- Build our ear containing EJB webservices
- Using `maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin` to start an embedded instance of Glassfish 3 during pre-integration-test maven ohase

  - Create my datasource as part of start goal
  - Deploy ear during deploy goal
- Still in pre-integration-test, I run liquibase:update on the same database URL. In this case a H2 file database
- I then want to run our SoapUI tests on the deployed application

But when i get this far the application can't find any data in the database. So the question is if I've missed something in my setup or if there's a better way to organize my intended goal?

pom.xml, embedded Glassfish

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <ports>
        <http-listener>9090</http-listener>
        <https-listener>9191</https-listener>
      </ports>
      <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
      <app>${project.build.directory}/school-application-${project.version}.ear</app>
      <name>school-application</name>
      <commands>
        <command>create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource --restype=javax.sql.DataSource --property URL=jdbc\:h2\:~/tmpLB\;AUTO_SERVER\=TRUE schoolDSPool</command>
        <command>create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid schoolDSPool jdbc/schoolDS</command>
      </commands>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.176</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>start</goal>
          <goal>admin</goal>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
          <goal>undeploy</goal>
          <goal>stop</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

pom.xml, Liquibase

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>company.school</groupId>
        <artifactId>school-db</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <systemPath>../school-db/target</systemPath>
        <type>jar</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.176</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
          <changeLogFile>db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
          <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
          <url>jdbc:h2:~/tmpLB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
          <logging>info</logging>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>update</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I have one changeset in the changelog inserting data in targeted tables.

1. Do I have the right users set up?
2. Is there a way to run Liquibase in the same process as Glassfish and use a `mem:` database instead?

Thx and regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there was an "easy" solution to the problem.

There was no data in the database since that changeset in liquibase changelog couldn't complete. I had the insert statements in a separate sql file that I called using the `<sqlFile>` liquibase  tag. But the insert was violating some foreign key constraints and didn't get executed.

So what put me off was the fact that Liquibase seems to hide any errors from included sql files. Will try try reproduce that and Jira it if I succeed.

/Christian